# Regex in variables

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a variable, lets call it `test = data.measurement.info;`

Now I want to set a regex so instead of measurement it will match anything.

I know the dot (match anything) can be used (.), but how do I include it in the variable?

Comment: so `data.*.info` ?

Comment: Unfortunately this gives: Parse error at '.' usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax.

Answer (score 1):

So, assume you have a list of names:

```
 test = {'data.measurement.info','data.123.info','data.measurement.123'};
 expression = 'data+\.+\w*+\.+info'; % \w* is any alpha numeric word; alternatively, if you just want anything, use a single . like 'data+\.+.+\.+info'

 regexp(test,expression,'match')

 ans = 

     {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {}
```

Comment: It also matches for example `'dataaaaaaa.measurement.info'` :)

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression matches the following:

"data" + exactly one "." character + at least one word character + exactly one "." character + info

```
testCell = {
    'data..measurement.info', ... % double "." is illegal
    'data.custommeasurement.info', ... % okay
    'data.123.info', ... % okay
    'data..info', ... % empty second part is illegal
    'data.measurement.123'}; % not okay

% data + exactly one "." + at least one word character + exactly one "." + info
expression = 'data\.{1}\w+\.{1}info';

regexp(testCell, expression, 'match')
```

*Output*

```
ans =  {}    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {}    {}
```